# How to subtract a year from leap year

Tags: php, leap-year

I'm looking for a solution for the following:

```
$date = new DateTime('02/29/2020');
$date->sub(new DataInterval('P1Y'));
$date->format('m/d/Y');
```

This Returns:  03/01/2019

Is there a way to return 02/28/2019?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date('L')` returns true if a leap year, so:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('02/29/2020');
$date->format('L') && $date->format('m-d') == '02-29' ? 'P366D' : 'P1Y';
$date->sub(new DateInterval($interval));
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/4mXX4

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is general:
Add or subtract a month to a date without jumping to the next month if the date 
is close to the end of the month. For a year, this is to add or subtract 12 months.

The algorithm for the addMonthCut() function was taken [here](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt).

```
function addMonthCut(DateTime $date,$month = 1) {
  $dateAdd = clone $date;
  $dateLast = clone $date;
  $strAdd = ' '.(int)$month.' Month';
  $strLast = 'last Day of '.(int)$month.' Month';
  if ($dateAdd->modify($strAdd) < $dateLast->modify($strLast)) {
    $date->modify($strAdd);
  }
  else {
    $date->modify($strLast);
  }
  return $date;
}
```

Examples:

```
$date = new DateTime('02/29/2020');
$date = addMonthCut($date,-12);  //-1 Year
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');  //02/28/2019

$date = new DateTime('02/28/2019');
$date = addMonthCut($date,+12);  //+1 Year
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');  //02/28/2020

$date = new DateTime('01/31/2020');
$date = addMonthCut($date,+1);  //+1 Month
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');  //02/29/2020
```